# Wexbim Files in Razor Pages

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, razor-pages, xbim

I am working on a razor pages project that needs to view IFC files, so I converted the IFC file into Wexbim files to use the XbimWebUi library.

My problem is when I use the Wexbim file from wwwroot I get this error "Uncaught Failed to fetch binary data from the server. Server code: 404. This might be due to the CORS policy of your browser if you run this as a local file.", so I uploaded my file to [Cloudinary](https://cloudinary.com/) website and got a link for it and it works well.

My question is how to do this throughout wwwroot folder without using an external link.

Thanks in advance.

**My Code**

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>xViewer</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">

    <script src="~/Viewer/gl-matrix.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Viewer/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Viewer/webgl-utils.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Viewer/xbim-product-type.debug.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Viewer/xbim-state.debug.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Viewer/xbim-shaders.debug.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Viewer/xbim-model-geometry.debug.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Viewer/xbim-model-handle.debug.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Viewer/xbim-binary-reader.debug.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Viewer/xbim-triangulated-shape.debug.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Viewer/xbim-viewer.debug.js"></script>

    <style>

        html, body {
            height: 100%;
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
        }

        canvas {
            display: block;
            border: none;
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="content">
            <canvas id="viewer"></canvas>

            <script type="text/javascript">
                var viewer = new xViewer('viewer');
                /*viewer.load("~/Uploads/SampleHouse.wexBIM");*/
                viewer.load("https://res.cloudinary.com/amostafah/raw/upload/v1623564775/SampleHouse_uacu4j.wexbim");
                viewer.start();
            </script>

        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hi @Ahmed Mostafa, did you add `app.UseStaticFiles();` middleware to support read static files?

Comment: I am using `app.UseStaticFiles();` @Rena , but unfortunately it does not work.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is actually related to Mime Mappings.
All you need is:

```
       app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
        {                
            ServeUnknownFileTypes = true
        });
```

You can check by accessing the path where you hold the wexbimfiles directly and serving a .png file from that folder. If you get it then the path is fine.

If you get 404 when accessing http://localhost:58802/data/SampleHouse.wexbim, then this is mime type related.